# Decently priced 10-Gigabit Ethernet switches?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, high-end

Are there any decently priced 10-Gigabit Ethernet switches? Any 5-port ones under $100?

I'm mostly asking out of curiosity, so this isn't an XY problem.

Comment: Absolute lowest price [I could bring one down for is 185.73](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIADP08GG7286&Description=switch&cm_re=switch-_-0XP-003P-002E7-_-Product). You'll notice that regardless of your low port requirement this switch has 24 ports. This just happened to be cheaper than switches with lower port quantities. I suspect that 10-Gigabit switches are only really used in enterprise level applications as you are unlikely to actually pass the Gigabit mark without the proper servers, cables, or otherwise environment.

Comment: 10GBASE-T, or is some other physical standard okay?

Comment: @BennettYeo You can even post this as an answer, since you identify precisely *why* such switches are expensive regardless of the port quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute lowest price [I could bring one down for is 185.73](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIADP08GG7286&Description=switch&cm_re=switch-_-0XP-003P-002E7-_-Product). You'll notice that regardless of your low port requirement this switch has 24 ports. This just happened to be cheaper than switches with lower port quantities. I suspect that 10-Gigabit switches are only really used in enterprise level applications as you are unlikely to actually pass the Gigabit mark without the proper servers, cables, or otherwise environment.

Comment: note: link broken but kept for archival purposes, probably broken due to being significantly out of date.